# libRestKitThree20 library is getting error

Tags: iphone, ios, three20, restkit

I have included restkit in project and when i build restkit, it builds successful. But when I build project, it gives 6 errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTModel", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectLoaderTTModel in libRestKitThree20.a(RKObjectLoaderTTModel.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTTableLinkedItem", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_RKMappableObjectTableItem in libRestKitThree20.a(RKMappableObjectTableItem.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTTableViewDataSource", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectTTTableViewDataSource in libRestKitThree20.a(RKObjectTTTableViewDataSource.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_TTModel", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RKObjectLoaderTTModel in libRestKitThree20.a(RKObjectLoaderTTModel.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_TTTableLinkedItem", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RKMappableObjectTableItem in libRestKitThree20.a(RKMappableObjectTableItem.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_TTTableViewDataSource", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RKObjectTTTableViewDataSource in libRestKitThree20.a(RKObjectTTTableViewDataSource.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

kindly help how to rid it off

Comment: You are sure this project is using three20? Could this be a build order issue - where you need to reference three20 in your workspace/project or even in the RestKit project?

Comment: Yes you are right @eanticev I solved it in this way already. That was the main problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your project is using the Three20 library. Also make sure your build order makes sense - you may need to reference three20 in your workspace/project before RestKit is compiled or in the RestKit project if you have one.